# CSS table have one row have overflow

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, css-tables

I need a CSS design that has three rows and fills the entire screen. The second row has three columns. Each column has three sections (top,middle,bottom). I want the last section, if it is too big, to have a scroll bar so the content doesn't flow off the page.

I have attempted this for a while but my main problem is the section I want to overflow doesn't make the scroll box, it just flows off the page. Is there a way to do this? maybe using `display:flex`?

Here is the basic concept of my code:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="header">
        Header content here
    </div>
    <div class="content table-row">
        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="top-content">

            </div>
            <div class="middle-contnet">

            </div>
            <div class="bottom-contnet">
                If this content is too big, then make this div an overflow-y:scroll
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="top-content">

            </div>
            <div class="middle-contnet">

            </div>
            <div class="bottom-contnet">
                If this content is too big, then make this div an overflow-y:scroll
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-col">
            <div class="top-content">

            </div>
            <div class="middle-contnet">

            </div>
            <div class="bottom-contnet">
                If this content is too big, then make this div an overflow-y:scroll
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer content here
    </div>
</div>
```

If you can help, please do.

Comment: where is your css code?

Comment: pls see my edited answer. if you find it useful pls check the checkmark beside it. it will appear on hover. it should turn green. (you can only do this with one answer). Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: i have edited my answer so you can run the snippet and enter full screen mode

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an additional class to the row so you can have a overflow class and apply it to only the specific row?

```css
.overflow: overflow-y: scroll;
```

```html
<div class="bottom-contnet overflow">
    If this content is too big, then make this div an overflow-y:scroll
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that. The problem is the bottom-content class doesn't have a fixed height, it fills the rest of the page. So the overflow doesn't apply, it just flows off the page